# Why can't extend DisplayObject then instantiate

Tags: actionscript-3, class, extending

The DisplayObject class can be extended but the extended class cannot be instantiated.

Class:

```
package{

    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    class Extended extends DisplayObject{

        public function Extended(){
            super()
        }
    }
}
```

Main timeline:

```
var e:Extended=new Extended();

addChild(e);
```

Error:

> ArgumentError: Error #2012: Extended$ class cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation of the [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) class:

> The DisplayObject class itself does not include any APIs for rendering content onscreen. For that reason, **if you want create a custom subclass of the DisplayObject class, you will want to extend one of its subclasses** that do have APIs for rendering content onscreen, such as the Shape, Sprite, Bitmap, SimpleButton, TextField, or MovieClip class.

Comment: dear null, Thank you again for your second answer to my questions.